# Are OnSleep and OnResume virtual methods in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

If they are not then is it important to have `base.OnSleep` and `base.OnResume` when I am adding code to those methods?

Comment: Xamarin is **Open Source**: you can see how it is implemented, there is no need to ask here

Comment: You could refer to the MS docs. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/app-lifecycle It shows the three virtual methods of App Lifecycle with how to override.

Comment: There seems to be confusion.  For example see the answer here where the poster says "When you override them, you should always call base.OnSleep() and base.OnResume()."

Comment: `OnSleep()` and `OnResume()` are the features provided by the Application base class. When you override the method, it would generate automatically. The override method would call the method in base class.

Answer (score 1):

Both of them are virtual methods.

When you override them, you should always call `base.OnSleep()` and `base.OnResume()`.

Here are the links to the docs:

- [OnResume](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.application.onresume?view=xamarin-forms)
- [OnSleep](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.application.onsleep?view=xamarin-forms)